# Detect Glide Pad "Smooth Scroll"

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am working on a site where when the user scrolls down using their mouse wheel (or glide pad) the site automatically uses jquery animate to scroll down to the next element.

The problem is that when using a Mac or any other device that "Smooth Scrolls", if the user swipes down on their glide pad a bit too fast, after the animation finishes, it gets called again.

The reason for this is that when you scroll using a glide pad that "Smooth Scrolls", it does not simply pass delta (- 40) to the site, instead it passes a whole bunch of deltas which usually start high like -100 and go down to -1 at the end of scrolling to give the user a smooth scroll finish as if the page is on ice and it is slowly regaining friction.

At first I tried limiting the site to only scroll if delta is greater that -50 or 50 which works great on devices that use "Smooth Scrolling" but for those that don't, the function never gets called since a mouse only sends about delta 10.

I have my code set up like this:

```
if (delta < 0) {
    //SCROLL DOWN
    scrollDown();
} else if (delta > 0) {
    //SCROLL UP
    scrollUp();
}
```

Before someone says that you should never hijack a normal use of the keys or mouse, google does it too and they have the same problem as me. I just want to make it perfect. Thanks!

http://www.google.com/glass/start/

Comment: yeah, I've seen this effect on a site before.  I think its a terrible user experience.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends how its used though. I also have a turn off feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who happens upon this, I have decided to go a different route.

**This is too hardware dependent and as far as I am aware, no way to tell.**